# Request had insufficient authentication scopes. while calling gmail api for list of messages using React

Tags: google-api

I am trying to return all messages from my gmail account, this is the code:

```
axios.get(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/${USER_ID}/messages`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
      }
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Running this code returns 403 with message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.ListMessages",
          "service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I took my access_token from `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/...`, this is the response:

```
    {
      "access_token": "access token used in request", 
      "id_token": "id token", 
      "expires_in": 3599, 
      "token_type": "Bearer", 
      "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
      "refresh_token": "..."
}
```

While using `https://developers.google.com/` everything works fine, but if I send request from my localhost I get the error.

My question is:

**What kind of scope do I have problem with and how do I change it to get right response?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You apear to be using [user messages list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)

this method requires one of the following scopes

[image]

your access token has only requested the consent for

- openid
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Which means **Request had insufficient authentication scopes.** you need to request the proper scope to be able to access that method

Comment: I am looking for a way to add scopes to my request.  I see examples where people use google packages to send request with scopes, can I add a scope in request using axios without installing google package?

Comment: You need to request authorization of the user again and request a new scope.  there is a extra paramater you can send that would let it keep existing scopes and just add more.  I cant remember what it is off hand.   Stop using oauth2 playground and do this with your own code.  playground is just for testing.